# Meshlab Crashing when running Remeshing, simplification - Quadratic Edge Collapse Decimation

Tags: meshlab, quadratic-programming, decimation

Good morning,

I have imported a .3ds and a .obj file into Meshlab and need to reduce the amount of faces. I do this usually and with no problem in the past using the Quadratic Edge Collapse Decimation function in filters.

Mesh lab has all of a sudden started to crash (completely close down - no error message) at the end of the process. I have two work computers that are doing the same thing. I have updated to the latest software version with the same result.

I'm not very tech savy when it comes to this stuff! Sorry.

Any help would be greatly accepted!

Mick

Answer (score 1):

when you get a crash into MeshLab, you should report the error in the [Issues](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues) tab in the official github repository!
List the operations you do to get meshlab crash, and if it is possible share the 3D object input file, in order to help the team replicate and then solve the issue!